# How do I round datetime column to nearest quarter hour

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, python-datetime

I have loaded a data file into a Python pandas dataframe. I has a datetime column of the format `2015-07-18 13:53:33.280`.

What I need to do is create a new column that rounds this out to its nearest quarter hour. So, the date above will be rounded to `2015-07-18 13:45:00.000`.

How do I do this in pandas? I tried using the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831018/python-how-can-i-round-a-datetime-object-to-the-most-recent-previous-quarter-h), but get an `'Series' object has no attribute 'year'` error.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Assuming that your series is made up of `datetime` objects, You need to use `Series.apply` . Example -

```
import datetime
df['<column>'] = df['<column>'].apply(lambda dt: datetime.datetime(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day, dt.hour,15*(dt.minute // 15)))
```

The above example to always round to the previous quarter hour (behavior similar to floor function).

**EDIT**

To round to the correct quarter hour (as in , if its 7 mins 30 seconds past previous quarter, to show the next quarter) . We can use the below example -

```
import datetime
df['<column>'] = df['<column>'].apply(lambda dt: datetime.datetime(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day, dt.hour,15*round((float(dt.minute) + float(dt.second)/60) / 15)))
```

The above would only take the latest seconds into consideration , if you want the millisecond/microsecond into consideration , you can add that to the above equation as - `(float(dt.minute) + float(dt.second)/60 + float(dt.microsecond)/60000000)`

Comment: I believe this answer is actually incorrect - since it will always round down to the quarter hour before it, instead of to the nearest quarter hour.

Comment: @ThomasMo updated the answer for that as well. Previous behavior would have been similar to `floor` behavior

Comment: Can We pass that to a function, like,  def secondBackAdjuster(numSec):
    if numSec > 30:
        numSec = 30
    else:
        numSec = 0
    numSec , # Applog['TimeCreatedAdj'] = secondBackAdjuster(Applog['TimeCreatedAdj'])

Comment: The answer is still incorrect. When the time is 7:59, this will try to do `datetime(y,m,d,7,60)`, and fail because 60 is invalid value for `minute`. @tworec has a much better answer and that should be accepted.

Answer (score 152):

You can use [`round(freq)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.round.html#pandas.Series.dt.round). There is also a shortcut [`column.dt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) for datetime functions access (as @laurens-koppenol suggests).

Here's one-liner:

```
df['old column'].dt.round('15min')
```

String aliases for valid frequencies can be found [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases). Full working example:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd    
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([pd.Timestamp('2015-07-18 13:53:33.280'),
                           pd.Timestamp('2015-07-18 13:33:33.330')],
                         columns=['old column'])

In [3]: df['new column']=df['old column'].dt.round('15min')  
In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
               old column          new column
0 2015-07-18 13:53:33.280 2015-07-18 14:00:00
1 2015-07-18 13:33:33.330 2015-07-18 13:30:00
```

Comment: If one want to round to the closest time below or above it is possible to use `floor` and `ceil`, respectively. See [code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.3/pandas/core/indexes/datetimelike.py#L112-L114)

Answer (score 18):

#### This looks a little nicer

`column.dt.` allows the datetime functions for datetime columns, like `column.str.` does for string-like columns

[datetime-like properties API reference](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#datetimelike-properties)

```
import pandas as pd

# test df
df = pd.DataFrame([{'old_column':pd.Timestamp('2015-07-18 13:53:33.280')}])

df['new_column'] = df['old_column'].dt.round('15min')

df
```

Answer (score 7):

Anand S Kumar's answer doesn't round to the nearest quarter hour, it cuts off the minutes to the nearest 15 minutes below it.

Actually, in your example `2015-07-18 13:53:33.280` should round to `2015-07-18 14:00:00.000` since `53:33.280` is closer to 60 minutes than 45 minutes.

I found an more robust answer for rounding in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463930/how-to-round-the-minute-of-a-datetime-object-python).

For your situation this should work:

```
import datetime

def round_time(time, round_to):
    """roundTo is the number of minutes to round to"""
    rounded = time + datetime.timedelta(minutes=round_to/2.)
    rounded -= datetime.timedelta(minutes=rounded.minute % round_to,
                                  seconds=rounded.second,
                                  microseconds=rounded.microsecond)
    return rounded

dt['dtcolumn'] = df['dtcolumn'].apply(lambda x: round_time(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're fine with rounding down to the nearest quarter-hour, doing `.dt.to_freq('15min')` would also work. Note that it would change the dtype, which might be desired.